# Setting Apache HTAccess Rewrite Rules on a Subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am using a subdomain URL for my test server.  Something like:

http://dev.mysite.com

I have the following in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1
RewriteRule ^about/(.*)$ /about.php?request=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

The above works well on the production (non-subdomain) set of URLs.  But it doesn't quite make the cut on my dev box.  For example, if I type in

```
http://dev.mysite.com/about
```

I get a 404 error.  But the following with the appended .php extension works.

```
http://dev.mysite.com/about.php
```

I am guessing this has something to do with the first rewrite condition that deals with the www subdomain.  How would I modify my .htaccess file to account for the dev subdomain?

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: @anubhava No errors after putting in extra text at the top of the file

Comment: That means your Apache config hasn't enabled .htaccess

Comment: @anubhava Thanks, I forgot to edit the httpd.conf file on the dev box.  Feel free to put this down as an answer

Comment: Glad to know your problem got resolved. I added these comments as an answer below to help future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your .htaccess is not enabled.

**Verify whether** your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

**To enable** `.htaccess` your `httpd.conf` file will need this line:

```
AllowOverride All
```

Answer (score 0):

You need at least `AllowOverride All` or `AllowOverride FileInfo` in order for the htaccess file to work in your server/vhost config. FileInfo is for things like mod_rewrite.

Additionally, make sure you have mod_rewrite loaded.

You'll also want to change this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
```

to:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
```

because mod_rewrite will recognize that `about` has a php file and make it so `/about/something` passes the `-f` test, resulting in `/about/something.php`.